# Merge two transparent images using PHP

Tags: php, image, merge, gd, transparent

I have been trying to merge two transparent images using below code.Base image is a fully transparent image used as a canvas.
I'm getting a result like the image below(1st image - result.png). How to make it fully transparent?

```
 function copyTransparent($src, $output, $srcWidth){  
      $x = 288;
      $y = 85;
      
      $bg = 'tranparent.png'; // fully transparent image as bg. 
      $margRight = abs(($x- $srcWidth)/2);
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($bg); 
      imagealphablending($img, false);
      imagesavealpha($img, true);
      // Copy from other  
      imagecopy($img,$src, $margRight, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y);    
      // Save PNG 
      imagepng($img,$output,9); 
      imagedestroy($img); 
 }

$png = 'testSign2.png';
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($png); 
$src = imagecreatefrompng($png);
$newHeight = 85; 
$ratio = $width / $height; 
$newWidth = ceil($newHeight*$ratio);  
$newImage = resizePng($src, $newWidth, $newHeight);
copyTransparent($newImage,"result.png", $newWidth);
```

[image: result.png]

[image: background image]

[image: second layer image]

Comment: What are you using $margRight for? You're introducing the variable in your function copyTransparent() by retrieving the absolute number of the sum '($x - $srcWdith)/2". But since you're setting $x to be a static value, I can imagine this would result in unexpected behaviour.

Also, you've got a typo in the variable $srcWdith   ($srcWidth)

Comment: @Kay Angevare I'm using $margeRight to align the second image at the center of the first image. $x will be always same in my application. I have edited the typo.